# What's wrong with the following code?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    string a;
    cin>>a;
    a.erase(a.end()-1);
    a.erase(a.begin()+1);
    string ge = "oae";
    a.insert(a.begin()+1, ge);
    cout<<a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't compile and i don't know why. Can you tell me what's wrong

Comment: What's the error compiler is givin'you?

Comment: Also, which compiler?  It's possible that you're using a nonstandard compiler, or with options that cause it to behave in a nonstandard way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/

```
string& insert ( size_t pos1, const string& str );
 string& insert ( size_t pos1, const string& str, size_t pos2, size_t n );
 string& insert ( size_t pos1, const char* s, size_t n);
 string& insert ( size_t pos1, const char* s );
 string& insert ( size_t pos1, size_t n, char c );
iterator insert ( iterator p, char c );
    void insert ( iterator p, size_t n, char c );
template<class InputIterator>
    void insert ( iterator p, InputIterator first, InputIterator last );
```

Your call to `std::basic_string<t>::insert` does not match any of the above overloads.

```
a.insert(a.begin()+1, ge);
```

needs to be

```
a.insert(a.begin()+1, ge.begin(), ge.end());
```

or

```
a.insert(1, ge);
```

Otherwise that code is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

`a.insert(a.begin()+1, ge);` is the problem.

The `string::insert` function takes an int as the first parameter, and you're passing in an iterator. What are you trying to do?

Comment: No overload of std::basic_string<t>::insert takes an int parameter. Some overloads take `size_t` parameters, but not one takes an int.

Comment: @Billy: interesting, my compiler spat out:

error C2664: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::insert(unsigned int,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::_String_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' to 'unsigned int'

I suppose I should have said "unsigned int".

Comment: Size_t is a typedef for unsigned int on your compiler. The standard does not define it that way, however. That could be unsigned long, or unsigned long long, or unsigned short, or any other similar type and conform to standard.

Answer (score 1):

Working version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    string a;
    cin>>a;
    a.erase(a.end()-1);
    a.erase(a.begin()+1);
    string ge = "oae";
    a.insert(1, ge);          // here
    cout<<a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 because it's correct and you're new, but in the future you're not likely to get upvoted just for posting corrected code. You need to explain why the code was incorrect to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `std::string::insert()` overload that takes an iterator and `string` set of parameters.  You might chose instead to use:

```
a.insert( 1, ge);   // use an index and a string
```

or:

```
a.insert( a.begin()+1, ge.begin(), ge.end());  // use an destination iterator, and 
                                               //  a set of iterators indicating a range
```

Note that this will allow your code to compile, but it may have some runtime problems, such as:

- if `a` is an empty string, then `a.end()-1` is undefined
- if `a` is an empty string, then `a.begin()+1` is similarly undefined